# How to gain remote access without a Monitor or TV?

Tags: sd-card, ssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prepare for ssh without a screen](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38/prepare-for-ssh-without-a-screen)

I just booted my Raspberry Pi for the first time and can not gain remote access.

My Pi runs the recommended Debian image found at the [downloads section](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads) from an SD-card.  After powering up, my router reports an unknown DHCP client to be at `192.168.0.142`.

```
$ ssh -p 22 pi@192.168.0.142
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.142 port 22: Connection refused
```

I do not own a TV and no digital display, either. How can I gain remote access to the operating system of my Raspberry Pi?

Comment: What distro are you using? Either way you may want to check this question http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38/prepare-for-ssh-without-a-screen

Comment: MY Raspberry Pi is running the recommended Debian image found at http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads

Comment: The linked post has a couple of ideas that should work to enable SSH, then assuming you have a windows PC you will need an SSH client like putty which you can get here: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/

Comment: I have Fedora 17 on my laptop. My router reports an unknown DHCP client to be at `192.168.0.142` and `ssh -p 22 pi@192.168.0.142` returns `ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.142 port 22: Connection refused`

Comment: the Debian image does not have SSH enabled by default. Did you check the answers in the other post I linked to?

Comment: I think I will just boot the SD-card on my Laptop and install and configure `sshd` from there.

Comment: Yes, I saw the other Q/A. Thanks for pointing me there. I checked just to verify (and to have an nice and naive question.)

Comment: Actually, the current Debian image *does* have the ssh server `sshd` installed which I could enable by moving `boot_enable_ssh.rc` to the `boot.rc` on the 78 MB partition.

Comment: Sorry i meant not enabled.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One can start the ssh server using the `boot.rc`. Below is an explanation of how that works.

#### Configuring the boot.rc

Insert an SD-Card with the Debian OS on it back into the machine, you copied over the image on. The operating system of that machine should mount the boot partition which is the first partition of the the SD-card. If it does not try something like this on Linux:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

On the mounted partition you will find a file `boot_enable_ssh.rc`, if you installed a recent version of the officially recommended Debian image. Back this file up, if you will and rename or copy it to `boot.rc`. To ensure your changes have been written to the SD-card, umount it and wait for the safe remove to finish. When you now boot the Raspberry Pi with that SD-card, it should come up with ssh running.

#### Finding the Pi and its SSH server

To connect to the Pi you need to gather the IP address of your Pi. This can be done by checking the device list of a router, usually responding under `http://192.168.0.1`, `http://192.168.1.1` or `http://192.168.178.1`. If that is not the case, you can scan your subnet for ssh hosts using `nmap`:

```
$ nmap -p 22 --open -sV 192.168.0.1/24

Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.142
Host is up (0.0094s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE VERSION
22/tcp open  ssh     OpenSSH 5.5p1 Debian 6+squeeze1 (protocol 2.0)
Service Info: OS: Linux; CPE: cpe:/o:linux:kernel

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (2 hosts up) scanned in 3.00 seconds
```

#### Testing

The interesting parts of the above output are the IP address and the port.
The IP address is in this case `192.168.0.142`, but can be different for you because it is determined by [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DHCP).
The port is in this case `22` and that should usually be the case, because 22 is the [reserved port for ssh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell#Usage).
With this information, one can test the ssh connection on the raspberry pi using something like this:

```
ssh -p 22 pi@192.168.0.142
```

SSH should ask for a password which is `raspberry` on current images; for the latest usernames and passwords see the section relevant to Debian of the [official downloads page](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads).

Answer (score 1):

On the root of the debian image, you will find a boot_enable_ssh.rc file. Rename it to boot.rc (rename the current boot.rc if there is one) and boot with that. ssh should now be running.

Comment: This answer is incomplete. Where is this file, if there is a current `boot.rc` file, wont overwriting it cause some issues?

Comment: The file is in the boot directory. This folder is on the first partition, and usually the only partition Windows mounts. There is no default `boot.rc` in the current debian image.

Comment: Can you see why I was confused? You did say: `if there is one`.

Comment: @teraquendya You are of course essentially right, but you answer contains information from comments, only and is not as extensive as I think is necessary for this to be valuable. Therefore I created my own answer and will accept it, when stackexchange allows me to.