# How can I access my mini-pc (RaspberryPi) via ethernet/wifi without having Monitor?

Tags: operating-systems, setup, wireless

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to gain remote access without a Monitor or TV?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/606/how-to-gain-remote-access-without-a-monitor-or-tv)

Well I have already asked the question [**here**](https://superuser.com/questions/440857/how-can-i-access-my-mini-pc-raspberrypi-mk802-mele-a1000-via-apc-via-eth) so am confused whether to post it again or not. Just to keep things simplified.. I have posted the link to my question above.

Moderators pls don't flame me..help me in shifting my question if appropriate (but it doesn't really belong to a single category (RaspberryPi) so I have posted it @ superuser.stackexchange

Comment: See this question: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/606/how-to-gain-remote-access-without-a-monitor-or-tv

Comment: thanks a lot :D yeah was just reading this here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38/prepare-for-ssh-without-a-screen

Answer (score 2):

You can use **ssh** to setup **VNC** on Raspberry Pi. VNC is a graphical desktop sharing system, like "Remote Desktop" - exactly what you need.

**Step 1 - Power it up**
By default *RPi* Distributions come with enabled dhcp and installed ssh server. So all you need to do is plugin your *RPi* into the network and check what IP address had it received (from your router active DHCP clients for example or by using *nmap*)

**Step 2 - Connect to it with ssh**
If you are using Windows download a tool called [PuTTy](http://www.putty.org/). It's a tool for remote console management.
If you are using Linux issue the `ssh ip_address_of_pi` command.
Next you will need to enter the login credentials for your Pi

**Step 3 - Install vnc**
Check what package manager is using your RPi Linux distribution. For Debian the default one is called 'apt-get'. Other package managers are 'aptitude', 'synaptic' and etc.
Run this to install vnc4server

```
sudo apt-get install vnc4server
```

That the most important. Follow some tutorial on the web for configuring vnc. There is an easy to use vnc client for windows and linux.

Good Luck!