# Would a Compaq Presario V6000 laptop monitor be just fine for the RPi?

Tags: power-supply, hard-drive, laptop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Connect Pi to an old laptop screen](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/848/connect-pi-to-an-old-laptop-screen)

My Compaq Presario V6000 laptop just had an HDD failure and I took it apart and salvaged the monitor. I was wondering if I could use the monitor for the RPi, or would I need more power for it? It's an LCD screen but I have no idea how much power it sucks up. I have very little idea what I'm doing with this, and all I can say about wires coming in/out of it is there are two wires, one black and one gray, and there seems to be a ribbon cable also. What kind of connections should I make? What about power supply for the monitor?

Comment: This might well be possible but is not trivial. [This question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/848/connect-pi-to-an-old-laptop-screen?rq=1) is very similar, a duplicate? Try to find a data sheet for your LCD, that would clarify the power issue as well.