# Raspberry Pi Video Output

Tags: gpio, video, display

Is there any way for me to use my laptop screen as a screen for my Pi (Model B)? The cost of a HDMI to VGA converter as well as a good monitor with HDMI connectivity are a little high.

I have a Raspberry Pi Model B. Unfortunately, the model comes only with an HDMI and Component port for output and not VGA.

As an experiment, I am trying to share the video output of the device directly to my laptop using internet.

Since, I cannot RDP without an operating system present on the device, is there an alternative solution?

Any way of using the GPIO ports provided?

Thanks in advance - Ananth

Comment: Display over network is a good idea. You can also do a lot by ssh from your laptop. As you say you need an OS for this. It's possible to get the Pi running without a monitor, and just doing the configuration over ssh. Many (most?, all?) popular SD card images come with ssh installed. Search for 'headless'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect Pi to an old laptop screen](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/848/connect-pi-to-an-old-laptop-screen) See also: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14611/how-to-set-up-raspberry-pi-without-a-monitor?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to 1) flash to an SD card a distro like [raspbian](http://www.raspbian.org/) then 2) power up your Raspberry Pi and access it via SSH using a client like [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) on your laptop (on the same LAN) with default credentials reported in your image, for raspbian defaults are:

- Host Name: raspberrypi
- username: pi
- password: raspberry

Then you can use the command line from laptop to the Raspberry Pi. If you want/have to use raspberrypi's IP and you have a router then access its backend and find the list of network devices, just look for "raspberrypi" hostname.

If you want graphical interface, you can 3) [install a vnc server](http://gettingstartedwithraspberrypi.tumblr.com/post/24142374137/setting-up-a-vnc-server) via command line to get all candies.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a screen with a DVI input, you may use an HDMI to DVI cable to connect the Pi, it works great.

If you have a TV with a HDMI input, you may use it as well.

Anyway, you are going to need an OS on the SD card to use the Pi.

Answer (score 0):

If you have older laptop then search for S-Video input. If you have it, then CVBS to S-VIDEO convertor should be much cheaper.