# Use cellphone screen as monitor

Tags: screen, output

This question is different from ([Connect Pi to an old laptop screen](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/848/connect-pi-to-an-old-laptop-screen)) because I will use a cellphone and not a laptop.

Would the Raspberry Pi support a LCD screen that is taken out of a cellphone?

Comment: THere area a gazzilion modles of screens. Whether they are laptop, cellphone, radio, fridge, toaster is not relevant. What is important is the technology used to interface with the LCD. Your question cannot be simply answered without speculating to all types of screens used. Which is impossible! Please find out what kind to connector technology the screen uses and update your question. If you can't find out how are we supposed to find out? Good question but it does not fit in with the rules of this site.

Comment: I find this very helpful!!! It seems that if you have an old phone you can simply use the phones hardware to drive the screen rather than having a seperate board drive it for you. Now im going to figure out if i could run the phone at very low power settings. thanks a lot !!!!!! http://joshuawoehlke.com/android-raspberry-pi-display-over-usb/

Answer (score 11):

Hackaday.com: USING CELL PHONE SCREENS WITH ANY HDMI INTERFACE

http://hackaday.com/2014/11/02/using-cell-phone-screens-with-any-hdmi-interface/

Has a video specifically using a raspi and iphone 4 screen.

Comment: In case the link goes dead, its a good idea to include what it is talking about (e.g. [the card used](https://hackaday.io/project/364-mipi-dsi-display-shieldhdmi-adapter))

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 10):

It is doubtful that the connections from a cell phone LCD screen would be optimal to use with your Raspberry Pi.  That said, I'm positive it's possible.

But, why even go to the trouble?  With multiple LCDs made specifically for the Raspberry Pi today (some of them touchscreens!), it is more practical to buy an LCD than to salvage one from a phone and use it.  Yes, [they can be a bit pricey](https://www.adafruit.com/category/63), but unless you are extremely determined to use this cell phone screen of yours, I would recommend to use one of those dedicated Raspberry Pi screens instead.  If you aren't determined enough to reuse this cell phone screen of yours, you are going to get very frustrated.

Comment: This is not an answer. Just an opinion of yours. I will leave the downvoting to others.

Comment: The first part is an answer, the second part is an opinion.  I do not see a reason for a downvote, since the question was answered - "Would the Raspberry Pi support a LCD screen that is taken out of a cellphone?".

Comment: You are first doubtful, then ask why go to the trouble and finally cast a shadow of possibility.  It just a poor answer to a poor question. You should have noticed that. For example. Can I use an ECU with an Engine? The question is poor and the answers will be poor.

Comment: I wasn't doubtful that it was possible, I was doubtful it would be easy - "I'm positive it's possible".  Yes, it isn't the best question, but without more specific data given by the OP, it isn't really possible to give a better answer.

Comment: So please explain how to do it. That is the purpose of a Q&A. Explaining a specific question....

Comment: I just stated that I couldn't, because I wasn't given enough data by the OP.

Comment: Exactly. So there is no flipping answer to the question. The question needs to be closed because it is to broad. Please vote to close it.... and you "answer" is more like a comment. Read my comment.

Comment: @ppumkin, true, but would cellphone screens work via DSI, GPIO, HDMI, RCA, or some RPi expansion board? Does the RPi have drivers to support such screens?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is possible.  You can achieve this by using a framebuffer driver from [the fbtft project](https://github.com/notro/fbtft).  According to the list of supported devices on the projects [wiki](https://github.com/notro/fbtft/wiki/LCD-Modules), Nokia 5110/3310 displays are supported.  These display modules are readily available on eBay.

Comment: Thanks! I never heard of the fbtft project. That will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I found this helpful,
[android-raspberry-pi-display-over-usb](http://joshuawoehlke.com/android-raspberry-pi-display-over-usb/)

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I am quite surprised to see that you took the time to explain the down-vote. Most users that down-vote typically do not explain why they down-voted or what can be improved.

Comment: @DevynCollierJohnson, in fact the down vote is not mine (I tend to comment w/o down votes). It is however unfortunate that the user is not inclined to follow the advice...

Comment: This link isn't relevant to the question. The OP wants to connect an LCD to his RPi, not remote desktop from an Android device.