# Connect dead laptop display to Raspberry pi?

Tags: display, laptop

I have a laptop where the motherboard died. I am wondering if I can "harvest" the display and connect it to a raspberry pi for little to no money. I have already taken the display out of the laptop and have not damaged it.

The display has a 40 pin connector that I believe is the thing that transfers power and video signal to the motherboard.

Any way this is possible? If not then what can I do with my dead laptop, besides taking the hard drive and using it for eternal storage on another device?

Comment: Welcome to RPi Stack Exchange! The first part of your question has an existing answer here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/848/connect-pi-to-an-old-laptop-screen?rq=1. The second part of your question is out of scope for this site as it does not pertain to the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't just throw it away: http://recycleyourelectronics.ca/

Comment: I will not throw it away. But here is another question, can I install android on a Raspberry pi v1 model A.?

Comment: @MicahFriesen I don't think it's possible to run android on Rpi v1 as it would be terribly slow. However, you can run lollipop on Rpi v2. Here is the link : http://raspex.exton.se/?p=43

Comment: YBy the way you probably can easily connect other parts as well - some pieces e.g. keyboard, webcam, bluetooth etc connect via internal USB bus, so it is quite easy to connect a cable to them and use them.