# HDMI-to-( TTL or LVDS ) decoder/driver on a custom PCB

Tags: hdmi, display, screen, driver, compute-module

I am working on a custom-made handheld PCB based around a PI Compute Module and one of the hardest steps I have found is **how to include an HDMI-to-(50pin-TTL or LVDS) driver on my PCB to run my LCD TFT 7" 1024x600 IPS panel.** First I have not found any available open-source driver board, either TTL, LVDS, or parallel RGB. The only alternative I have found is the [Adafruit TFP401](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-tfp401-hdmi-slash-dvi-decoder-to-40-pin-ttl-display) board, but it is only compatible with Adafruit's low-resolution (800x480) 40pin TTL screens. Higher resolutions TTL screens often come with 50 pin connectors. Also, I know the pi's MIPI display connector is closed-sourced and only works with pi's expensive and low-resolution screens.

**In summary, do you know any open-source HDMI-to-TTL or LVDS driver PCB design I can use for my project? If so, could you also share the schematics and compatible list of screens available for this driver? Thank you.**

Maybe I am looking at it from the wrong perspective. If you would have to add an LCD driver to your custom PCB, how would you do it?

Comment: There is displays with SPI interface and thats much simpler to work with, fewer pins.

Comment: Thank you, @MatsKarlsson. The SPI interface is more common for very low resolutions panels, i.e. 2.8", 3" and maybe 5". The display I need requires a size of 7" and a resolution of 1024x600, which are usually driven using LVDS or TTL interfaces.

Comment: Not really a duplicate, but check out this question: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/848/33476 . There are tons of HDMI to LVDS boards on sale like LAMV56, LAMV29, TY2662, etc.

Comment: Thank you, @DmitryGrigoryev. There are a lot of cheap boards but what is needed is a schematic I can use to include one of these drivers into a custom PCB and the software to bootload the driver chip.

Comment: @RubenA.Chevez I think "Electrical Engineering" could be a more appropriate group, try https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ I know there are more electronic engineers there and I think thats what you are looking for.