# Unable to connect to Pi over SSH (no keyboard, no monitor)

Tags: ssh, sd-card, connection

I used to be able to connect to my Pi over SSH but after an erase + reinstallation of Raspbian (after lost of pwd),  I now get a `port 22: connection refused`.

I got latest Raspbian installed on the Pi (downloaded [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads) and installed following these [instructions](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/mac.md)).

I've checked [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38/prepare-for-ssh-without-a-screen) and [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/606/how-to-gain-remote-access-without-a-monitor-or-tv) but I don't have any `boot_enable_ssh.rc` file on the `boot` partition and I'm not able to edit the `ext3` partition (I'm using a Mac) so I can't perform *Oli's* solution.

I've also tried to `Rename /etc/rc2.d/ssh/K??ssh to /etc/rc2.d/ssh/S02ssh` but it didn't work.

Thusly :

1. How can I check if SSH is indeed enabled on my Pi without any
   computer or keyboard ?
2. And if it's not how to enable it ?

Btw, when doing a `nmap`, I've noticed that my Pi got a strange name `l.home`:

```
Nmap scan report for l.home (192.168.1.15)
```

Any help would be strongly appreciated !

Comment: What command are you using to connect? Are you using the IP or the name? How is the Pi connected to the network?

Comment: @SteveRobillard : I'm using
`ssh pi@192.168.1.15`. The Pi is connected to the network via an Ethernet cable connected to the Router.

Comment: can you ping that IP address?

Comment: If your install is a fresh, official Raspbian, SSH is enabled by default.

Comment: That strange name looks as though there was a typo in the script command that set the name of the RPi.  e.g `echo 1 > /etc/hostname` rather than `echo $1 > /etc/hostname` in a script where `$1` was the first argument that was supplied on the command line of the script. Is your network supposed to be called `home` - if not, check `/etc/networks`...

Comment: @SteveRobillard : yes I can  `64 bytes from 192.168.1.15: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=2.442 ms`

Comment: @SlySven Yes `home` is my network. But it's a "L" rather than a "1"

Comment: @Havnar : I've downloaded `2016-02-09-raspbian-jessie.img` from [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads)

Comment: Did you do a checksum after downloading? And after the dd, did you run the sync command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally done an ersatz of [Oli's solution](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1706/42212) by :

1. installing `OSXFuse` and `fuse-ext2` to mount the ext3 partition.
2. use the `-o force` option of `fuse-ext2` in order to write on the ext3 partition.
3. do the loop myself, i.e. rename each `K**ssh` in `rc$i.d` `(for i=1 to 6)` to `S02ssh`
4. Reboot the Pi.

I'm not sure that enabling ssh on every runlevels is a very safe option but at least, it works that way.
Anyway, this is strange that official Pi's documentation claims that SSH is enabled by default on Raspbian even though it seems that this is not the case.