# Running Headless - checking boot screen messages

Tags: boot, headless

It's fairly easy now to run headless from scratch with a Raspberry Pi.

One area that might have an issue though is debugging issues with devices that have been added to the Raspberry Pi. Often you get indication of these problems in the messages that scroll through during boot.

Are these messages echoed anywhere - to a log - or are they only available if you connect a monitor during boot?

Comment: The title of this question sounds terrifying.

Comment: if you are using raspbrian (you probably are), then installing `bootlogd` will add boot logs. I did not have any boot logs on my laptop running debian-x86, until I installed this package.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, there are logs for everything.

If you connect a new device to the Pi then the module being loaded will show in `dmesg`. Eg;

```
$ dmesg | tail 
[16037.102139] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
[16037.102299] scsi4 : usb-storage 2-2:1.0
[16037.102422] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[16037.102425] USB Mass Storage support registered.
```

All other logs will have their place in `/var/log/`. Some important ones include:

- `/var/log/boot` -  For all boot messages, such as daemons starting.
- `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` - All Xorg logs. Including any errors.
- `/var/log/errors.log` - Any system error will also be logged here.

Comment: If you ssh into the running headless pi, then typing dmesg at the command prompt will do this for you.

Comment: @Amos yes it will do this for you

Comment: As mentioned in another answer: you need `bootlogd` to have boot messages (daemons startup messages) in `/var/log/boot.log`

Comment: Try `journalctl --boot`

Answer (score 44):

You can see bootup messages by connecting to the UART on pin 14/15 of the GPIO port

Here is how to connect it to one of the PL2303 UARTs that can be found on ebay for a few dollars.

I didn't need to connect GND because I am powering the RPi from a USB port on the same computer.

If you just want to see the boot messages, you'd only need the orange wire. If you want to log in once it boots, you'll need the purple wire too.

If you need to connect GND, it should go to the pin to the left of the orange wire.

[image: PL2303 UART]

Set the serial port to 115200 baud and you are all set

Comment: I really need to get one of those! My remote headless Pi just failed to start up properly after a full update. Kind of ugly if you cannot `ssh` into the system any more to check the logs.

Comment: But what software do you use on your other computer to connect?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel, Any terminal emulator: on linux I usually use minicom or screen. putty on windows

Comment: Just to mention rx from one side should be connected to tx at the other side and opposite for  tx. Also don't forget to connect GND pin if you're using a separate power supply (other that usb) for rpi

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for systemd boot messages, you could find them in `/var/log/boot.log` (I think you have to install `bootlogd` for that) or in the virtual console `/dev/vcs1`.

`vcs1` is just one line so you could format it with `fold` or `fmt`

For me it worked with: `# fold -w 148 /dev/vcs1` (each line = 148 columns)

Note: corrected device file name typos