# Raspberry Pi Won't Boot

Tags: boot, power

I have tried multiple operating systems...

- Raspbian
- Debian
- OpenElec
- Raspbmc

Two different SD cards...

- Sandisk 2gb BE1210021871G
- Sandisk 4gb

And two different Raspberry Pis. I cannot get any combination to boot. I followed the OSX install guide and have also tried to install from my Linux box as well.

When installing/booting I get a load of USB errors like...

> raspbmc unable to enumerate usb device on port 1 (even when there are no USB ports connected)

Then after the first boot when I try turn it on again it just hangs on a black screen. Any ideas?

Comment: What power supply are you using?

Comment: The default RS components one.

Comment: What is its maximum output current? What peripherals have you got plugged in?

Comment: 1200mA No peripherals.

Comment: If the power supply is the only thing in common, it makes sense to suspect it.

Comment: What were the exact commands you used to flash your SD card?

Comment: The ever-present USB device is the hub/ethernet chip, unless you have somehow obtained a model A without.

Comment: If you can hook up to the serial port, you can get a copy of the boot messages to add to your question. http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1231/590

Answer (score 5):

As others have mention, suspect your power supply.

From the Raspberry Pi Blog "[Counterfeit power supply units in the UK](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/2151)":

> Everybody testing returned units used in the UK has noted a problem out there with some power supplies, all of which appear to be counterfeit Apple chargers. We’ve all compared notes, and we’re all seeing the same thing: some of you are using chargers you’ve bought in good faith which are not the real thing, and which don’t behave like a safety-tested, properly engineered piece of hardware