# How to investigate why device crashed?

Tags: raspbian, debian

My Raspi after 6 days of uptime just crashed. I wasn't able to see nothing on the screen, if I plugged a USB device, no action from it. And all the LEDs were steady and not a blink at all.

I have the debian distro.

I am trying to detect what could be the cause of the crash. I wanted to check the logs but for example I have zero sized messages:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 0 Oct 14 06:25 /var/log/messages
```

dmesg shows just current startup screen, and it doesn't provide any notice of some errors.

Where shall I look forward?

**Update**

I restarted yesterday too, and checking in the morning and it's crashed again.

**Update**

The raspi frezzes multiple times a day, problem got worst. I updated firmware and still happens, I tried ran memtester and it reported no memory issues.

Comment: Are you perhaps mounting `/var` in RAM? If so the error messages wont persist after a reboot :(

Comment: I have there some error messages from apache, from several days ago.

Comment: I think you'll have to go the UART route as gnibbler says then.

Comment: Are there any files like /var/log/messages.1 or 1.gz? That would mean the logs got rotated and the old messages are moved to these files.

Comment: If the file is unexpectedly truncated, check to make sure the volume (card/partition) isn't full! Full storage is a common cause of worry, grief, and potential strange failures on all systems.

Comment: And yes, dmesg prints the ring buffer from the **running kernel** and so can't print anything older than when the kernel was started (boot). It also starts to discard the oldest messages when the ring is full so you may only have the most recent ones in a long-running system.

Comment: Disk is used 55%.

Comment: Sounds like your SD card is malfunctioning. Have you tried a different card?

Comment: @Jivings I am just doing that, so far after a couple of hours everything looks OK.

Answer (score 5):

If your PC is nearby, you can leave the serial port connected like [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1231/590) in case it crashes again. Mine crashed once like this and I could see the kernel panic etc. in putty.

If plugging in the USB device is what caused it to crash, you may be able to replicate it. Also suspect the power supply - the power supply to the USB is not very well engineered in the revision 1 boards.

Comment: As the update tells the situation got worst, I have multiple frezzes on the same day. I have no chance momentarily to try out the system you are recommending. Is there somehow I could leave SSH open, and see the kernel panic. Also how to check if it's from the power supply. I have a 5v/1000mA adaptor. After crash the LEDs stay in lit mode.

Comment: Oh, power supply on rev1, really? Which models?