# Raspbmc first boot without tv

Tags: raspbmc, screen

Do I need a monitor to do the first boot with Raspbmc? I know it needs wired internet connection to update and all how long does it usually take? (I have a very fast connection)
I can hook up a keyboard if needed for first boot. Otherwise i will just ssh to get my stuff together.

Comment: Take a look at this question. It outlines how to get everything working to use SSH without using a screen, including how to configure a static IP address so you don't have to figure it out the hard way, and so that it maintains the same IP every time even after reboots. http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38/prepare-for-ssh-without-a-screen

Answer (score 5):

The first boot doesn't need any interaction. The second boot will start `ssh` and generate the keys.

You'll have to figure out the IP by looking at your router or attempting to ping the Pi.

You can log on over `ssh` with the default credentials.

The only issue here is that if the first boot script fails for any reason you won't know about it. I have a 20MB connection and it took around 10 minutes.

Comment: How does one know the 'first boot' has finished, and has finished successfully?

Comment: @klokop Your Raspberry Pi will be on, and be showing a user interface.

Comment: Hm, in my case the downloading of root fs etc. took FOREVER (quite literally), and the unit kept rebooting. Switched to different OS.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a computer nearby, you can watch the bootup messages from the [serial port on the GPIO](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1231/590)