# How do I set up a terminal log-in via USB port in Raspbian?

Tags: usb, peripherals, serial

How can I set up a log-in focused on a USB port so I can hook up a DB9-to-USB cable *I already own* up to log in using putty or minicom?

Comment: What is the OS of your other computer?

Comment: Xubuntu 12.04.2

Comment: Alternatively just use the [console on the GPIO header](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1231/590)

Comment: Right now I want to use the Commercial Off The Shelf hardware I do possess which is the DB9 to USB cable which is hooked up to a serial port already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do 2 things to make this work:

- Make the USB->serial cable always use the same device name when you connect it.
  [This article on noctis.de](http://noctis.de/ramblings/linux/49-howto-fixed-name-for-a-udev-device.html) and [this article on redhat magazine](http://www.redhat.com/magazine/002dec04/features/udev/) describe how you can do this.
- Have the system run `getty` on that serial device.
  Add a line like this to your `/etc/inittab`:

  ```
  T1:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -L **{Device name from step one}** 115200 vt100
  ```

I have not done this with my RPi (or any Linux system) so I don't know how feasible this is.