# raspberry pi not booting correctly

Tags: raspbian, boot

I started using a raspberry pi 2 model B today. I installed raspbian using noob. It boots up and all the commands scroll through the screen and once that's finished all that shows up on the screen is a blinking underscore. I found this [issue](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43658/raspberry-pi-2-doesnt-boot-correctly) and tried getting to the terminal as suggested but to no avail. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but NOOBS causes more problems than it solves.  Try downloading Raspbian from here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/  You will need a program to flash the software onto an SD card.  Use balenaEtcher, which is free and available here: https://www.balena.io/etcher/  If your computer does not have a way to mount an SD card, you'll need a USB adapter.  Get a good one.  I've had success with these: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B009D79VH4/

Comment: Try using Ctrl-Alt + F[1-6] (meaning, hold ctrl-alt down and slowly cycle through the first six F- keys) and see if anything happens.  Wait a few seconds each time.  You can't damage anything this way, this is just for switching between the [virtual console interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console) provided by the kernel.   It may be that the GUI has started, but it is assigned to a different VC.  There may also be console logins working on at least one of them.

Comment: @BobBrown why not use the new RPF/RPT imager tool that does the same job as Etcher but doesn't need a seperate download of plain Raspbian - it does the whole job in one shot.

Comment: @Dougie  The imager tool has been available to the public for only a few weeks, and I am absolutely, positively, certain that the process I described will work. A year from now it's possible that the imager tool is what I'll recommend.  Right now, for someone who's already having trouble, I want to offer a solution that's a bullet-resistant as possible.  (Don't forget, an author of the imager tool is also an author of NOOBS.)

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, i did some digging on the side and i believe it may have been due to a lack of space on my SD card which I have upgraded. That seems to have done the trick but i will take into consideration your suggestions if this ever happens again.