# No boot-up message through GPIO serial port

Tags: archlinux, serial-console

I am using a CP2102 Module to connect my PC with the Pi's GPIO port. Although there are some errors but now I can see some output every time I reboot the Pi.

```
[   49.739893] systemd-cgroups-agent[177]: Failed to get D-Bus connection: Failed to connect to socket /org/freedesktop/systemd1/private: Connection refused
[   49.757494] systemd-cgroups-agent[178]: Failed to get D-Bus connection: Failed to connect to socket /org/freedesktop/systemd1/private: Connection refused
[   50.958737] Restarting system.
```

I believe this means the physical connection and the hardware works OK. However, unlike [what this article descripted](http://elinux.org/RPi_Serial_Connection), there are no boot up messages, nor can I access the console login.

The Pi is running ArchlinuxARM, what can I do to activate the serial console?

**UPDATE**

(Content moved to the answer.)

Comment: Perhaps ArchlinuxARM doesn't use the UART for the console by default

Comment: Emm... So why the shutdown message shows?

Comment: No idea. [PL2303 module worked fine for me](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1231/590) with raspbian

Comment: Are you using `screen` or `minicom`? I can confirm `screen` works with the CP2102, but minicom gave me problems. Also, does `ps aux | grep getty` shows a process running? (Paste the output if you don't understand it)

Comment: I was using `minicom` and `gtkterm`. I will try `ps aux | grep getty` when possible.

Comment: Try `screen` I had the exact same problem with that chip using `minicom`.

Comment: @GuySoft I have enabled the serial console and it works fine for both `screen` and `gtkterm`, `minicom` is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following some suggestions in the comment, `ps aux | grep getty` shows no `ttyAMA0` instances so the serial console is not started. Following the [official Archlinux guide for Raspberry Pi](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Raspberry_Pi), I enabled the console:

```
systemctl start getty@ttyAMA0
systemctl enable getty@ttyAMA0.service
ln -s /usr/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@ttyAMA0.service
```

I can now connect to the serial console. By editing the `cmdline.txt` as the following, the kernel message shows up as well:

```
loglevel=5,console=ttyAMA0,38400 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,38400 (...other options)
```

**FURTHER TIPS**

If the Pi is powered by the PC through a USB cable, since they share the same ground, only `TxD` and `RxD` need to be connected. If the Pi is using another power source, Connect the `Ground` cable as well otherwise the console will keep receiving rubbish data.

Comment: Glad I could help out :) (a vote up to my helping comments would be nice)