# Headless wifi configuration ( AP mode )

Tags: wifi, setup, headless

I'm looking for a solution for configuring wifi in headless mode, the same way as IoT devices : when not known wifi in range, toggle to AP mode with a predefined SSID, run a small web-server to list available network, and provide inputs to enter network Key.

I didn't find anything, so I'm eager to develop something to solve the problem.

So does someone know a premade solution ?
If not, how should I proceed ? Write a script that modifies wicd/wpasupplicant config files ?

Answer (score 3):

The [***google coder project***](https://googlecreativelab.github.io/coder/) does exactly this and I've used it successfully to enter wifi credentials and connect a headless Raspi to a wireless network.

- copy the coder image to an SD card.
- Connect to the headless Raspi via a web browser on another computer. The computer must be on the same network as the Raspi.
- To access your Coder, allow time for it to boot, then visit ***http://coder.local*** on your computer.
- The Raspi, booted with the coder image, starts a web server and after logging into the site a password can be entered to connect to any detected SSID on the next boot.

Answer (score 2):

This might be interesting:

https://github.com/sabhiram/raspberry-wifi-conf

The app is not 100% stable. I still have some problems as described in issue #12.

Comment: Have to try, but it seems to do the job !
Since I ask the question, another project came to life : https://github.com/resin-io/resin-wifi-connect a module from resin.io framework

Comment: many thanks for the link, this sounds really interesting. I will try to install it on my pi :-)

Comment: I have tested resin-wifi-connect. It requires to download a resin.io image and is not exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: It can't be used as a standalone tool ? what a shame :/

Comment: I could not use it as a standalone tool. I had to enter my wifi credentials on the resin.io website before downloading the image. Yesterday I found this repository on Github: https://github.com/jasbur/RaspiWiFi It might be an alternative. I haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and easy working solution.

https://github.com/balena-os/wifi-connect

Comment: I wish you would read about [Markdown formatting](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/editing-help), and use it in your posts. :)

Comment: "In most cases, a plain URL will be recognized as such and automatically linked:"
..
"To create fancier links, use Markdown:"

I have just registered quickly to share my conclusion and help others. I don't want fancy links. 

I wish you would be less cynical. :)

Comment: Cynical?! If I'd said anything cynical in my comment, I would apologize for it. But I won't apologize for being insulted by you - someone who won't even bother to learn the [meaning of a word](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cynical) before insulting someone who is trying to inform you.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to setup an IoT like network; it will be very painful (a loads of work has to do to make it automate).

For your question I want to share what I have done for automatic network connection. You will have to develop a mobile app (in my case it was android).

First, I gave each device a name and a psk. Then run an encryption on the name and get the generated SSID. Then configure this SSID through wpa_supplicant or hostapd.

```
base_64(encrypt(ssid + 'delimiter' + psk)) ==> your hostapd/wpa_supplicant ssid
```

In you android app get the scan list run decryption on the name (only your devices will succeed others will fail). extract SSID and psk. configure wpa_supplicant using the SSID and key.

```
network_info = split(decrypt(base_64(scan_list)), 'delimiter')
ssid = network_info[0]
psk = network_info[1]
```

hope this helps :)