# Wireless issues headlessly setting up Pi Zero

Tags: wifi, headless, pi-zero

I very recently got a Pi Zero and would really like to start using it. I, unfortunately, do not seem to be able to connect to it. I installed Raspbian on the SD card, attached a Wi-Fi dongle, and installed PuTTy (I'm using it for my Linux class as well, so it works fine). I watched a YouTube video, where in the `cmdline.txt` document, they set the IP address at the end of the document... `ip=169.254.1.1` I did exactly this, waited a minute, and attempted to use PuTTy to connect, which timed out. Twice.

Is this an acceptable way to connect? Does the IP address need to be something in particular, or should any number (with the correct number of digits) work?

My `cmdline.txt` is now as follows...

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1
root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline
fsck.repair=yes rootwait ip=169.254.1.1
```

Comment: Did you enter the WiFi key (WPA2 encryption) ?

Comment: @flakeshake Ah, yes. I followed this question and replaced it with my information... http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10251/prepare-sd-card-for-wifi-on-headless-pi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

169.254.0.0/16 is a fallback address range which hosts can use when they don't get a reply from the DHCP server.

If you force the pi to use `169.254.1.1`, you'll have to add a `169.254.x.x` address to your PC

Usually it's easier to use DHCP. Most people these days have a modem or router that is capable of DHCP server duties.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for! If you happen to know, does this mean that I should not assign the IP address, and instead try to find it on the network via the router?

Answer (score 0):

If your access point is configured with a password (and I cannot imagine why it would not be) you can also preconfigure that. Just search for "raspberry pi wifi_supplicant.conf." (I could find nothing here but you will find plenty of links.)