# How do I create a file "wpa_supplicant.conf" in the boot directory in Raspberry Pi?

Tags: ubuntu

In order to prepare my RPi for connecting to Wifi, I need to do some changes as per [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10251/prepare-sd-card-for-wifi-on-headless-pi).
Now, I cannot find the file: `wpa_supplicant.conf` in the boot directory. Hence, I need to create it and then save the mentioned changes. The issue is: I am unable to write into the directory. File cannot be saved and it shows "read only disk." I have tried `sudo chmod -R 777 boot/`  but in vain.

Note: I am using a memory card reader to read the card used in the RPi.

Comment: Is the SD card [write locked](https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1102/~/sd%2Fsdhc%2Fsdxc-memory-card-is-write-protected-or-locked) by any chance? Might you have inadvertently flipped the switch (if your SD card has one)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Aurora said, make sure your sd card is not write-protected:

[image: write protection]

and make sure you formatted your sd card as FAT32 before you wrote the os to it.(I recommend using a tool like [etcher](https://etcher.io/) to burn the image.)
also, if you have an ethernet cable, you can connect your raspberry pi to your router with an ethernet cable, ssh into and add the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` file to it over ethernet, then disconnect it and reboot it so it connects to the wifi.

Comment: hope you get it working! :)

Comment: Turns out, the fault was in my sd card reader, a new one was working. The old(corrupted) one was sorta always write protected.