# Set a static IP address for wlan0 from /boot partition of Raspberry Pi on Raspbian Stretch Lite

Tags: wifi, boot, static-ip, cmdline.txt

I am using Raspbian Stretch Lite 2018-04-18. I currently have static IP working over wifi. I setup `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` to connect to my wifi and setup `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` to use a static ip:

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.0.101/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1
```

But, instead of making changes to the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file I would like to be able to set the IP address of the Pi from a configuration file located in the /boot directory so that I can easily change it by mounting the sdcard on a Mac computer, which automounts the /boot partition. This will allow me to easily provision multiple pis with different IP addresses.

I know you can setup a static ip for ethernet using [/boot/cmdline.txt](https://kr15h.github.io/RPi-Setup/), so I did try adding `ip=192.168.0.101::192.168.0.1:255.255.255.0:rpi:wlan0:off` to this file, but that didn't work. This [thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=191123) seems to imply setting ip in cmdline.txt only works for ethernet.

Comment: You can create a symlink from /etc/dhcpcd.conf to /boot/dhcpcd.conf and place that file there.

Comment: Thanks Janka. That seems like it should work, i'll test and let you know. This person, https://harizanov.com/2014/09/exposing-raspberry-pis-network-setting-files-to-boot-so-that-they-are-visible-on-a-pc/, seems to think that works.

Comment: @Janka You can't create a symlink on FAT

Comment: And? The symlink is on the / fs, not /boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Thanks for your suggestions Janka. Follows is a full answer.

First edit `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` and `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` so you are connected to the network the way you want.

Then create the symlinks (also making backups of these config files):

```
sudo mkdir /boot/network
sudo cp /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf           
/boot/network/wpa_supplicant.conf
sudo mv /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf 
/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf.backup
sudo ln -s /boot/network/wpa_supplicant.conf 
/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

sudo cp /etc/dhcpcd.conf /boot/network/dhcpcd.conf
sudo mv /etc/dhcpcd.conf /etc/dhcpcd.conf.backup
sudo ln -s /boot/network/dhcpcd.conf /etc/dhcpcd.conf
```

Now you can edit `/boot/network/dhcpcd.conf` and `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` when mounting your sd-card from Windows or Mac.

Note that I placed the config files at `boot/network` instead of directly in `boot`. I did this because the Pi, I discovered, [already has a process](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/57023/87464) that looks for a file at `/boot/wpa_supplicant.conf` and moves it to  `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` when found. Since I eventually want to enable [read-only Raspberry pi](https://learn.adafruit.com/read-only-raspberry-pi?view=all) this copy operation would have been problematic, so placing `wpa_supplicant.conf` at `/boot/network/wpa_supplicant.conf` avoids this process.