# Raspberry Pi connected to WiFi but not the internet

Tags: raspbian, networking, pi-3

My problem is that, after connecting my Rpi to the home Wifi network, it refuses to connect to the internet.  Funny thing is: I am connected to it via ssh.
I tried to ping google, but it said:

> connect: Network is unreachable

Then I tried to ping google`s IP, but the same thing happened.
I tried the method described [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12919/how-to-debug-no-internet-connection) but nothing is working.  How can I get my pi to connect to the internet?

If this might be any help, here is the output of `route -n`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     201    0        0 lo
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
```

I had my pi connected to this network before and I have set it to a static IP "192.168.1.23".  It used to work but it suddenly broke and `hostname -I` gives the following output:

> 192.168.1.23

So everything seems to be correct aside from the fact that I cannot reach everything (literally everything, even localhost is unreachable).  And one more thing: I am connected to WiFi via a repeater.  Thanks in advance.

PS: My question is not a duplicate of this [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12919/how-to-debug-no-internet-connection). I have searched pi StackExchange but nothing worked.

**EDIT:**

I used the WiFi management GUI To set the static IP on my Pi.

Comment: Would you be able to confirm whether you can access the internet when connected through ethernet?

Comment: "I have set it to a static IP" but have NOT said how, and the evidence of IP routing table is otherwise. See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: @Deleuze Unfortunately I have no ethernet cable.

Comment: @Milliways I have used the Rpi Wifi settings Manger to do it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Guys But I found the answer
Everything worked after I  reset the configuration in my `/etc/network/interfaces`
to

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

,thanks anyway

Comment: This worked for me too.

Comment: I cannot get this answer to work with Raspbian Stretch.  Results in the RPi3 wifi to remain non-functioning.

Comment: This is the most direct & best answer and worked for me. Thanks for the quick fix.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem using Wi-Fi, I had also to change:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
```

to:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

Then the internet connection worked