# No input on FTDI / Serial on raspberry

Tags: serial, headless

I have one of these: 
 [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00FEAMUOK/ref=oh_details_o02_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FEAMUOK)

Hooked it up as described in in the last post here: 
[Running Headless - checking boot screen messages](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/949/running-headless-checking-boot-screen-messages/1231#1231)

I get output; 
[image]

But I cannot type / provide input. I get the cursor, but I can't send any keystrokes.

Thoughts?

EDIT: Over on the raspberry pi forums someone said I probably fried the UART-RX pin/circuitry w/ the 5 volt board. I bought a sparkfun basic 3.3v FTDI board. Receive works on the computer end, but I still cannot send to the Pi. I see an activity light on the FTDI board so I assume it is something wrong with the pi.

Is there anything I can do to re-assign the UART pins, or test this further?

Comment: I might be wrong but I think its read only via the TX/RX pins (the way you have it configured). You would need to SSH via putty to communicate with the Pi.

Comment: No, it should function as an input/ receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that the pin is dead. The code to run this test is available in the wiringpi library http://wiringpi.com/

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/wiringPi-05e2f67/gpio $ ./pintest
PinTest
=======

This is a simple utility to test the GPIO pins on your revision 2
Raspberry Pi.

NOTE: All GPIO peripherals must be removed to perform this test. This
  includes serial, I2C and SPI connections. You may get incorrect results
  if something is connected and it interferes with the test.

This test can only test the input side of things. It uses the internal
pull-up and pull-down resistors to simulate inputs. It does not test
the output drivers.

You will need to reboot your Pi after this test if you wish to use the
serial port as it will be left in GPIO mode rather than serial mode.

Please make sure everything is removed and press the ENTER key to continue,
or Control-C to abort...

          The main 8 GPIO pins  0: 7:  OK
The 4 pins on the P5 connector 17:20:  OK
                The 5 SPI pins 10:14:  OK
               The serial pins 15:16:
 --> Pin 16 failure. Expected 1, got 0
One fault detected.
                  The I2C pins  8: 9:  OK


Faults detected! Output of 'readall':
+----------+-Rev2-+------+--------+------+-------+
| wiringPi | GPIO | Phys | Name   | Mode | Value |
+----------+------+------+--------+------+-------+
|      0   |  17  |  11  | GPIO 0 | IN   | Low   |
|      1   |  18  |  12  | GPIO 1 | IN   | Low   |
|      2   |  27  |  13  | GPIO 2 | IN   | Low   |
|      3   |  22  |  15  | GPIO 3 | IN   | Low   |
|      4   |  23  |  16  | GPIO 4 | IN   | Low   |
|      5   |  24  |  18  | GPIO 5 | IN   | Low   |
|      6   |  25  |  22  | GPIO 6 | IN   | Low   |
|      7   |   4  |   7  | GPIO 7 | IN   | Low   |
|      8   |   2  |   3  | SDA    | IN   | High  |
|      9   |   3  |   5  | SCL    | IN   | High  |
|     10   |   8  |  24  | CE0    | IN   | Low   |
|     11   |   7  |  26  | CE1    | IN   | Low   |
|     12   |  10  |  19  | MOSI   | IN   | Low   |
|     13   |   9  |  21  | MISO   | IN   | Low   |
|     14   |  11  |  23  | SCLK   | IN   | Low   |
|     15   |  14  |   8  | TxD    | IN   | Low   |
|     16   |  15  |  10  | RxD    | IN   | Low   |
|     17   |  28  |   3  | GPIO 8 | IN   | Low   |
|     18   |  29  |   4  | GPIO 9 | IN   | Low   |
|     19   |  30  |   5  | GPIO10 | IN   | Low   |
|     20   |  31  |   6  | GPIO11 | IN   | Low   |
+----------+------+------+--------+------+-------+
```