# Using android phone's sensors on raspberry pi

Tags: networking, hardware, android

I'm new to raspberry pi. I was wondering if it was possible to connect an android phone to raspberry pi so that Rpi can read the data from the phone's sensors. It could be a direct USB connection. Ideally I would like to use the phone for its 3g connectivity, gps and accelerometer. 
I'm going for this method, as the individual hardware meant for Rpi is quite expensive, and I have android phones just lying around.

Comment: You will need a dedicated app on the android phone. You will have to do it over TCP. For direct USB connection [see this thread](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7810/ssh-from-android-to-rpi-using-usb/7829#7829)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install python on your phone it will help you accesses the sensors, i use qpython on my android tablet, the module that you want to use is androidhelper, it will contain the tools to read the sensors.

http://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/downloads/detail?name=androidhelper.py

But this link is all of the documentation that i have managed to find.

Another way would be to write a program using java that could read the sensors, this method will most likely give you the most options but it will be the most challenging.

Answer (score 4):

You can try using [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.zwiener.wimu&feature=also_installed#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwNCwib3JnLnp3aWVuZXIud2ltdSJd). It sends data from the sensors in UDP.
It would only give you the information from the Accelerometer from the list you wanted.

Sensor id:
3 - Accelerometer (m/s^2)
4 - Gyroscope (rad/s)
5 - Magnetometer (micro-Tesla uT)

Example UDP packet:
890.71558, 3, 0.076, 9.809, 0.565, 4, -0.559, 0.032, -0.134, 5, -21.660,-36.960,-28.140

Timestamp [sec], sensorid, x, y, z, sensorid, x, y, z, sensorid, x, y, z

There is a sample program in the description:

```python
import socket, traceback

host = ''
port = 5555

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
s.bind((host, port))

while 1:
    try:
        message, address = s.recvfrom(8192)
        print message
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        raise
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
```

The pi can run this program, since its python with only standard libraries.