# How do I install the Android Debug Bridge (ADB) on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian, android

I want to use ADB (Android Debug Bridge) on my Raspberry Pi.

How can I setup it up?

Comment: You want ADB command?  Do `sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb`

Comment: I just did `sudo apt-get install adb` and it got installed and works! maybe they added a support for it since this question's data.

Comment: you need compile from code using link below
https://github.com/qhuyduong/arm_adb

Answer (score 5):

I ran accross this problem 1-2 years ago and after a long search I ended up compiling adb myself. Also, because the available adb binaries are outdated. I needed **adb v1.0.32** and I could find only v1.0.29. Other adb binaries I found did not work because they were build for other CPU platforms (i.e. not ARM).

So lets compile adb on the Raspberry Pi itself - without any cross-compiling madness. It was actually easier than you'd think. All you should need is **git** and **gcc** (and the package libssl-dev, which is installed by the bash script).

Using some steps from [here](http://android.serverbox.ch/?p=1217) I made the following 2 files

1. **adb-compile-env-setup.sh**

   ```
    #!/bin/bash

    # some steps found here: http://android.serverbox.ch/?p=1217

    sudo apt-get install libssl-dev

    mkdir -p ~/adb-dev/5.1.1
    cd ~/adb-dev/5.1.1

    mkdir system
    mkdir external

    cd system/                
    git clone -b android-5.1.1_r1 https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core
    git clone -b android-5.1.1_r1 https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras

    cd ../external/                 
    git clone -b android-5.1.1_r1 https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/zlib
    git clone -b android-5.1.1_r1 https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/openssl
    git clone -b android-5.1.1_r1 https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/libselinux

    cd ../system/core/adb

    cp ~/adb-dev/Makefile .

    echo "Ready to hit *make* now and pray?"
    read -rsp $'Press any key to continue...\n' -n1 key
   ```
2. **Makefile** (place into ~/adb-dev/Makefile before running other script)

   ```
    # standalone Makefile for adb
    # found on: http://android.serverbox.ch/?p=1217
    # this works with android-5.1.1_r1

    SRCS+= adb.c
    SRCS+= fdevent.c
    SRCS+= adb_client.c
    SRCS+= commandline.c
    SRCS+= console.c
    SRCS+= file_sync_client.c
    SRCS+= get_my_path_linux.c
    SRCS+= services.c
    SRCS+= sockets.c
    SRCS+= transport.c
    SRCS+= transport_local.c
    SRCS+= transport_usb.c
    SRCS+= usb_linux.c
    SRCS+= usb_vendors.c
    SRCS+= adb_auth_host.c

    VPATH+= ../libcutils
    SRCS+= socket_inaddr_any_server.c
    SRCS+= socket_local_client.c
    SRCS+= socket_local_server.c
    SRCS+= socket_loopback_client.c
    SRCS+= socket_loopback_server.c
    SRCS+= socket_network_client.c
    SRCS+= load_file.c

    VPATH+= ../libzipfile
    SRCS+= centraldir.c
    SRCS+= zipfile.c

    VPATH+= ../../../external/zlib/src
    SRCS+= adler32.c
    SRCS+= compress.c
    SRCS+= crc32.c
    SRCS+= deflate.c
    SRCS+= infback.c
    SRCS+= inffast.c
    SRCS+= inflate.c
    SRCS+= inftrees.c
    SRCS+= trees.c
    SRCS+= uncompr.c
    SRCS+= zutil.c

    CPPFLAGS+= -DADB_HOST=1
    CPPFLAGS+= -DHAVE_FORKEXEC=1
    CPPFLAGS+= -DHAVE_SYMLINKS
    CPPFLAGS+= -DHAVE_TERMIO_H
    CPPFLAGS+= -DHAVE_SYS_SOCKET_H
    CPPFLAGS+= -D_GNU_SOURCE
    CPPFLAGS+= -D_XOPEN_SOURCE
    CPPFLAGS+= -I.
    CPPFLAGS+= -I../include
    CPPFLAGS+= -I../../../external/zlib
    CPPFLAGS+= -I../../../external/openssl/include

    # so well, let's fake HAVE_OFF64_T, because Raspbian does not.
    # just stay away from files larger than 2GB, ok?
    CFLAGS+= -O2 -g -Wno-unused-parameter -DHAVE_OFF64_T

    LIBS= -lcrypto -lpthread -lrt

    # old cross-compiler stuff 
    #TOOLCHAIN= /opt/poky/1.5/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-
    #CC= $(TOOLCHAIN)gcc
    #LD= $(TOOLCHAIN)gcc

    TOOLCHAIN= /usr/bin/
    CC= $(TOOLCHAIN)gcc
    LD= $(TOOLCHAIN)gcc

    OBJS= $(SRCS:.c=.o)

    all: adb

    adb: $(OBJS)
        $(LD) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

    clean:
        rm -rf $(OBJS)
   ```

Run the first bash script directly on your Raspberry Pi. Once it is finished, run `make`. This should compile the adb binary right on the Pi using Android 5.1.1 R1 sources - **no cross-compiling environment needed**!

*Remark*:
My comment in the Makefile

```
# so well, let's fake HAVE_OFF64_T, because Raspbian does not.
# just stay away from files larger than 2GB, ok?
```

I have never tested the "2GB problem", so I don't know how my adb build will behave, i.e. when you do `adb push verylarge4GBfile.img`. Maybe files larger than 2GB will work nonetheless - maybe not. Please let me know if you ever come across any problems in regards to this possible limitation.

I am running my adb binary on around 20-30 Raspberry Pi (v2 and v3) without any problems since approx. 2 years. It is used on a variety of android phones, but mostly android 4.4.x and android 5.1.x phones. Especially `adb forward` is working perfectly (which was not available in adb v1.0.29 as far as I remember).  `adb push` with ~1GB files works fine too.

**UPDATE:**
Sorry for the broken tabs/spaces in the Makefile above. I don't know how to fix this here, you'll have to fix it in the editor of your choice.

I was not able to compile any recent adb for arm on a Raspberry Pi so far, even after upgrading to Raspbian 10/buster which offers `gcc 8.3.0`.
It also comes with `adb v1.0.39, 1:8.1.0+r23-5`.
And to my surprise, `Raspbian 11/bullseye` actually includes `adb v1.0.41, 28.0.2-debian`
Even better, bullseye is also available for arm64 now!

Comment: When I was testing this solution what I did was just copy and pasted above 2 scripts and executed. An error occurred "Makefile:79: *** missing separator.  Stop." : Solution - Replace leading spaces with tabs of line 79 & 82

Comment: If you run adb-compile-env-setup.sh script as itself, you are required to make the adb-dev sub-directory inside the home sub-directory.

Comment: If an error like "make: *** No rule to make target 'adb.o', needed by 'adb'.  Stop." occurred, make sure that Makefile is inside the system/core/adb/ (This directory structure should be created after running the adb-compile-env-setup.sh)

Comment: After compiling it successfully, it still wasn't finding the devices. I had to run the adb binary with sudo and that fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me on Raspbian-Buster:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install adb
```

Answer (score 3):

[This thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1924492) from the XDA Forums (*"ADB for Raspberry Pi"*) might be helpful; a user there managed to compile ADB and produced a binary for it.

The binary itself can be downloaded from [this page](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=1392336&d=1349930509).

After unpacking using `p7zip -d <file.7z>` and copying the binary file mypart/out/host/linux-armv6l/bin/adb to /usr/bin it seems to be working fine on a RPi.

(I didn't have much time to compile it myself just for the test, but instructions should be on the page mentioned above)

Comment: That first link is from 2012.  Do you think it still has working info?

Comment: This answer is not up to date, links seams dead ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ubuntu Mate on Raspberry Pi., and install adb. It works.
I used it two days ago, and all my 3 devices got detected (Samsung S6, MotoX, Samsung Alpha).

Comment: Hope it worked ! It has to. 
If it worked, Upvote and confirm my answer as well, Thanks !

Comment: Nah, I like Raspbian.  Why would I install Ubuntu Mate?

Answer (score 0):

As for now, there are packages android-tools-adb, android-tools-adbd, android-tools-fastboot, android-tools-fsutils, android-tools-mkbootimg available for Raspbian. To me these were enough.

Comment: Do you mean to install all of these packages from the "Raspberry Pi OS" repository with `apt install`? Could you please add this to the answer?

Comment: Exactly. The command to do it is
`apt install android-tools-adb android-tools-adbd android-tools-fastboot android-tools-fsutils android-tools-mkbootimg`