# Wifi shared through ethernet cable [Ubuntu]

Tags: raspbian, ethernet, ubuntu

I have a laptop connected to wifi. I would like to connect my Raspberry Pi to it with an ethernet cable and have access to internet thanks to the laptop connection.

I have found a lot of partial solutions on the internet, but nothing that worked properly AND survived reboot (I managed twice to get internet access, but after reboot it stopped working and further modifications destroyed the working configuration). Would anyone have any idea of what are the files that need to be set up properly on both side? I work with Ubuntu on my laptop, Raspbian on the Raspberry Pi.

**[EDIT]**
**1) CURRENT SET UP**
***Laptop side:***
**/etc/network/interface**

> auto lo
>   iface lo inet loopback
>   iface eth0 inet static
>           address 192.168.1.1
>           netmask 255.255.255.0
>           network 192.168.1.0

**/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server**
Added the line

> INTERFACES="eth0"

**/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf**

> ddns-update-style  none;
>   default-lease-time 3600;
>   max-lease-time 7200;
>   authoritative;
>   subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
>     option routers 192.168.1.1;
>     range 192.168.1.100 192.168.1.200;
>   }

***RPi side***
Nothing has been modified. It is basically Raspbian after going through raspi-config after install but nothing else at all.

**2) PROCEDURE**
i) Run the following script on the laptop

> #!/bin/sh
>
> # bring up the eth0 interface
>     sudo ifup eth0
>
> # start DHCP service
>     sudo service isc-dhcp-server start
>
> # enable forwarding from the ethernet to wireless router
>     sudo /sbin/iptables --table nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE

ii) Connect the RPi to the laptop thanks to the ethernet cable
iii) Connect to the RPi via ssh (this works perfectly)

**3) VARIOUS OUTPUTS**
***Laptop side***
**tail /var/log/syslog** right after connecting the RPi

> Aug 10 17:22:19 shinagan kernel: [ 1257.119401] atl1c 0000:05:00.0: atl1c: eth0 NIC Link is Up<100 Mbps Full Duplex>
>   Aug 10 17:22:19 shinagan dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.1.100 from b8:27:eb:ce:d4:9e (groundStation) via eth0
>   Aug 10 17:22:19 shinagan dhcpd: DHCPACK on 192.168.1.100 to b8:27:eb:ce:d4:9e (groundStation) via eth0

**hostname -I**

> 192.168.1.1 10.0.0.2 10.10.0.82

**ip route**

> default via 10.10.0.81 dev tun0  proto static
>   10.0.0.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.2  metric 9
>   10.10.0.1 via 10.10.0.81 dev tun0  proto static
>   10.10.0.81 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.10.0.82
>   169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000
>   173.193.211.195 via 10.0.0.1 dev wlan0  proto static
>   192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1

***RPi side***
**hostname -I**

> 192.168.1.100

**ip route**

> default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  metric 202
>   192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.100  metric 202

**ip neigh**

> 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 lladdr f4:6d:04:fd:1e:a1 DELAY

**ip neigh show**

> 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 lladdr f4:6d:04:fd:1e:a1 REACHABLE

**ping -c3 192.168.1.1**  [that's the laptop adress. Works well]

> PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
>   64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.514 ms
>   64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.573 ms
>   64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=0.619 ms
>
> --- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
>   3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
>   rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.514/0.568/0.619/0.051 ms

**ping -c3 8.8.8.8** [google dns. Cannot connect...]

> PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
>   Then it hangs forever...

**ping -c3 www.google.com**  [does not resolve the address]

> ping: unknown host www.google.com

Reference to documentation on the matter or explanations would be a plus, as my knowledge of the phenomenons is limited!

Comment: This question is better suited to [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) than here, as the problem you're facing is Linux and network related. You might even search there for this.

Comment: Internet worked as soon as SSH started working for me: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3867/ssh-to-rpi-without-a-network-connection/53823#53823