# Ubuntu 17.04 direct shared Ethernet connection fails with "Active connection could not be attached to the device."

Tags: ethernet, ubuntu

I had direct Ethernet connection without a router working in Ubuntu 16.04 for SSH as explained at: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/53823/33424

But when I tested again 17.04, set "Shared to other computers", and select that connection, an error dialog appears:

> Connection activation failed.
>
> (0) Active connection could not be attached to the device

The only thread I could find was: https://askubuntu.com/questions/856007/failed-to-add-activate-connection but "All users may connect to this network" is already checked.

RPI 2 + Raspbian Jessie 2016-05-27 and 2017-04-10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the cause of this issue it is advisable to inspect the system logs, while the problem occurs.

To do so, open a console (maybe as root/sudo) then you can follow the logs like so: Generally `journalctl -f` and specifically for NetworkManager issues `journalctl -f -u NetworkManager`.

Now try to activate the connection and see what might hint you to the cause of error.

In my case I think I upgraded like you did (16.something to 17.04) and found dnsmasq missing, with one log line saying `<error> ... (eno1) failed to start dnsmasq: Could not find "dnsmasq" binary`.
This was solved by installing the package dnsmasq. It is [recommended](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dnsmasq) to install **dnsmasq-base** (e.g. `sudo apt-get install dnsmasq-base`).

There is a bug report to pre-install `dnsmasq-base` by default on Ubuntu at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1678606 since it breaks the network sharing GUI feature.

Comment: Which commands did you use to solve the problem? E.g.: `sudo apt-get install dnsmasq-base`?

Comment: I installed the package dnsmasq, but I just read, it is recommended to only install dnsmasq-base as you suggested, I will add this to the answer. :)

Comment: Cool! I will try this out later.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly! Edit in as well the bug report to pre-install `dnsmasq-base`: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1678606