# Controlling the Pi 3 via a USB cable to a smartphone without an internet connection?

Tags: pi-3, usb, ssh

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3 and I need to control it through my phone when I'm outside via USB.

I spent my entire day looking for solutions but none of them worked for me. I thought it might be simple just to control the Pi, (terminal) through SSH by using USB. E.g. A USB to micro USB cable plugged into my phone so I can send commands when I'm in the street with **no internet connection**.

Is it possible to do that With a USB cable? I also can't use a USB to TTL Serial Cable because it's not available in my area.

Answer (score 1):

The [Pi Zero allows ssh over USB](http://blog.gbaman.info/?p=699) but the 3 doesn't. You can also access it through [ethernet and serial](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3867/ssh-to-rpi-without-a-network-connection). Another method would be to have an internal network. A router doesn't need to be connected to the internet to connect devices.

Answer (score 0):

The Raspberry Pi 3 cannot act as USB device. The Micro-USB port on the Pi3 is also impossible to reconfigure for data transfer since the lanes are simply not connected at all.

The easiest way is to **turn your Phone into a hotspot** and have the Pi join that WiFi network.

Or [**turn your Pi3 into a hotspot**](https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/) and have your Andriod phone connect to it instead.

This does **not need** an real internet connection on either device !