# SSH over USB - possible with RPi 0 but not with RPi 3?

Tags: pi-3, ssh, pi-zero

Although I see [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/67695/controlling-the-pi-3-via-a-usb-cable-to-a-smartphone-without-an-internet-connect) and [there](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/55928/ssh-the-pi-from-computer-with-a-usb-cable-only) that SSH over USB is not possible with RPi 3, it seems that [SSHing over USB is possible for RPi 0](https://desertbot.io/blog/ssh-into-pi-zero-over-usb).

This seems weird to me.

**Do you (dis)confirm that SSH over USB is possible with RPi 0 but not with RPi 3?**

Comment: confirmed. Although re

Comment: @Dirk Thanks. What do you mean with "Although re"?

Comment: Aah. Hit enter at the wrong moment ;)

Comment: I should have added that this is because of gadget/slave mode. Only Pi0 (and derivatives) and Pi A/3A support this. The others don't because they have an onboard USB hub

Answer (score 2):

> This seems weird to me.

It's for the same reason you cannot connect the USB ports on your laptop to your desktop and use SSH over that.

USB is not a symmetrical protocol, meaning the two parties in a relationship are not equals.  One is the master, and one is the slave.  This is controlled in hardware, and although I believe it would be pretty simple to make a standard USB A port serve either role, conventionally they do not, I presume to prevent accidents, since plugging a master into a master can cause physical damage to one or both machines -- which is why you should never plug an A port into another A port (male-to-male cables for which are in fact hard to find).

Anyway, USB type micro-B ports are often implemented as [OTG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go), meaning they can be used as either master or slave.  This is how the one on the Pi zero works. SSH, which is TCP/IP based, is possible in that context when the Zero is configured to behave like an ethernet link.