# Is USB Pass through possible?

Tags: usb

I'm a new user to Raspberry Pi and this is my first Pi project. I'm running the latest version of Raspbian.

**Question:**

How do I configure my **Raspberry Pi 3 B+** to map one USB port to another? One port has a thumb-drive and the other would be connected to my vehicle radio.

**Background:**

I have a radio receiver in my pickup truck that can play mp3, mp4 content stored on a USB thumb drive when plugged into the radio.  When I want to change the content it always takes me several days to remember to bring the thumb-drive in, several more to change the content, then several more to remember to take it back out.  I thought putting Pi in between the radio and thumb-drive would be a cool hack.

**What I've done so far:**

I've permanently mounted a thumb-drive to the Pi. When I pull into the driveway, the Pi automatically connects to my home WiFi and shows up on my PC as a mapped drive.

- I can manually drag and drop content to it or..
- My NAS automatically backs up from a share to the USB drive on the Pi. I can sit at my computer in the evening, drop content into the share and overnight the NAS synchs the Share's content with what's on the Pi's thumb-drive.
- Transfer rate is 8-10 MB/sec which is plenty fast enough for me.

Thanks!

Comment: you are asking the wrong question ..... you do not want to map any USB ports ..... all you want to do is to `use an RPi to emulate a thumb drive`

Comment: As @goldilocks points out this is not possible with Raspberry Pi **B** models - because their USB connections are all USB-A type sockets which are connected to a USB hub which has to be the up-stream connection.  However the Zero models only have a single micro USB A connection which has the feature that it is wired directly to the SoC at the heart of an RPi and can be switched to the [**O**n-**T**he-**G**o](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go) mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You can't.

Devices which have USB passthrough are *slave* devices -- keyboards, cases, etc.  The Pi 3 cannot be used as a slave device.  I'll repeat myself [from here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/91465/5538):

> USB is not a symmetrical protocol, meaning the two parties in a relationship are not
> equals. **One is the master, and one is the slave.** This is controlled in hardware, and although I believe it would be pretty simple to make a standard USB A port serve either role, conventionally they do not, I presume to prevent accidents, since plugging a master into a master can cause physical damage to one or both machines -- which is why you should never plug an A port into another A port (male-to-male cables for which are in fact hard to find).

If your car stereo has a standard USB A jack that you can plug a thumb drive into, that port is a *master*.  So are the ones on the Pi 3, end-of-story.

As per the quote, this is the exact same reason you cannot connect your laptop to your desktop using a USB cable for data exchange.

You could use a Pi Zero, which has OTG functionality (see the link above), to emulate a thumb drive, as jsotola suggests.