# I want to use a Rasberry Pi as a USB A/V device to a windows computer

Tags: usb, webcam

Some background might help further this discussion.

We have multiple classrooms that have a variety of USB cameras and microphones installed in them.  I want to use a Raspberry Pi to help manage the different devices and present a single, unified USB webcam device back to the Windows computer.

The problem is that with multiple devices, faculty are unsure of which is the right device to select as a microphone or a camera in their recording, Zoom, or Skype.  I want to present them with a single choice and leave the management of the various devices up to the configuration on the Pi.  In some rooms there may be a simple cheap webcam, in others there might be a high end PTZ camera and an array of microphones, or a mix of all of the above.

Is such a thing possible?  Or would it all be able to mix it out the HDMI port and then be something we could convert to USB from there?  I'd rather have it as a USB device and avoid the extra hardware if possible.

Comment: My thinking is that the PI would simply show up as a USB Microphone/Camera and with it being the only such device presented in Windows be the defaults for both.  Now I believe I could get around that by having the PI always show the contents of whatever camera devices are plugged in out it's HDMI port and also send whatever audio out that port as well and then use an external HDMI converter (like a Magewell) to do the conversion.  I'm just wondering if there might be a way to avoid that extra step.

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/92453/5538 The model 4 has some potential because of the USB-C port, but I haven't heard of anyone actually implementing pass through with it.