# Extremely slow ssh on RPi Zero W

Tags: ssh, pi-zero-w

I have installed

- postfix
- dovecot
- fail2ban
- postgray

daemons on top of the 
Linux mail 4.14.98+ #1200 Tue Feb 12 20:11:02 GMT 2019 armv6l GNU/Linux

Also, I have connected rpi0 to another rpi over usb-otg (to have a serial and ethernet access).

Unfortunately, even though rpi0 has low load, when ssh to it, every typing takes seconds, and in lot cases connection break due to timeout.

```
  CPU[#*                        3.2%]   Tasks: 54, 17 thr; 1 running
  Mem[|||||||####*********87.6M/433M]   Load average: 0.02 0.04 0.05
  Swp[                         0K/0K]   Uptime: 23 days, 02:36:02
```

When I connect to rpi0 via serial link - everything works fine, no delays, no timeouts.

So, question is -- which software may cause a delay?

Comment: Please connect your devices and put the dmesg or /var/log/syslog output here and your boot cmdline.txt for more informations, 
because here it is very difficult.Maybe a conlict with the ethernet gadget and the serial interface ?

https://learn.adafruit.com/turning-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget/serial-gadget
https://learn.adafruit.com/turning-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget/ethernet-gadget
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/67907/debugging-usb-otg-serial-on-the-pi-zero-w

Comment: As you can see on Adafruit tutorial, it is an ethernet gadget OR a serial gadget... I don't known if you can use in the the same time two gadgets. good question.

Comment: But Serial can be acceded by USB from here you see how to : https://hackaday.com/2016/02/25/giving-the-pi-zero-usb-ethernet-and-serial-over-usb/

Comment: You need **COMPOSITE USB GADGETS**. This [tutorial](http://www.isticktoit.net/?p=1383) covers emulating a keyboard, ethernet adapter, serial device, etc...

Comment: It is possible to have both ethernet and serial using g_cdc

Comment: dmesg https://pastebin.com/i4WN0k8U

Comment: pi@mail:~$ cat /boot/cmdline.txt
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=68a6cc13-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait modules-load=dwc2,g_cdc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94393/discussion-between-andrii-zhuk-and-ephemeral).

Comment: Ho yes, sorry, I read "A composite CDC gadget". Also, I read [that] (https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/77059/what-does-dtoverlay-dwc2-really-do) it's not really encouraging "So you have to expect to very different performances (and bugs) with both drivers.
(for dwc2) ".Do you have an error loop or are it is your hot plug tests in your dmesg? .I do not see any device disconnects, I guess it is a bug for the moment .. .

Answer (score 2):

Uncommenting the following line in /etc/ssh/sshd_config did the trick for me, and my ssh session were not slow anymore afterwards:

```
UseDNS no
```

Don't forget to restart the ssh service after modifying the config file:

```
service ssh restart
```

Answer (score 0):

UseDNS didn't help me. What finally did was to go into the pi's ssh_conf and sshd_conf and add

```
IPQoS 0x00
```

It is suggested that an alternative might be to add

```
-o IPQoS=0
```

to the client's ssh command line, and that it might be worth changing that value from `0` to `throughput`.

Basically, open-ssh tries to use the Quality of Service figure for the connection to optimize its performance... and the default assumes a reliability that the Pi Zero W, with its weak WiFi hardware, can't reliably achieve. That causes long timeouts and loss of connection. Setting IPQoS to "we know it's a bad connection" makes the protocol less efficient but lets it recover from problems much more quickly.

Hope this helps others. Now I need to look up the packet-level details of what this setting does to the SSH protocol...