# Can I use ethernet to start Raspberry Pi for the first time

Tags: boot, networking, ssh

I bought a new Raspberry Pi Type B. The problem is that I dont have HDMI connectivity and Video o/p.

Can I SSH into the box? After a brief search on google, I understand that SSH is not installed by default. Is there any OS available for Raspberry Pi that comes pre installed with SSH. Or are there any good alternatives?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prepare for ssh without a screen](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38/prepare-for-ssh-without-a-screen)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [Raspbian](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads), ssh is enabled by default the last time I checked. So yes you should be able ssh into the RPi provided that port 22 is not blocked. IE: You should be able to ssh into the RPi from your internal LAN.

As a side note, you might want to buy a HDMI to DVI converter cable. Just in case you ever need to plug your RPi into a screen. You know, to jam some Quake 3.

Comment: Also enabled in Arch Arm.

Answer (score 6):

You could try [Occidentalis](http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-raspberry-pi-educational-linux-distro/occidentalis-v0-dot-2), which is a tweaked-version of [Raspian](http://www.raspbian.org/). A feature of this distribution that you may like is the ability to access your Pi without knowing its IP address, as it uses [Multicast-DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) to respond to such a request :

```
ssh pi@raspberrypi.local
```

Very handful !

As a side node, [Occidentalis](http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-raspberry-pi-educational-linux-distro/occidentalis-v0-dot-2) is also preconfigured to easily use the hardware pins of the Pi : i2c, spi and all kinds of GPIO ports.

Comment: +1 Neat, `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` just worked for me in Occidentalis!

Answer (score 3):

`sshd` is enabled by default. Did you try to connect?

If the OS is configured to setup the network via DHCP, you will need to look in your router DHCP pool to get the IP address the OS has been assigned.

If not, you will need to take the SD card out of the Pi, mount it on another linux box and edit the network configuration. It's better to do it this way, then you can assign a static IP and avoid the fuss of ping sweeping/checking router settings to get the IP address.

Comment: Which file to bed edited in SD card?

Comment: Presuming you're running Rasbian: `/etc/network/interfaces`. See this page: http://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Configuring_the_interface_manually for instructions.

Comment: It's not really correct to say "sshd is enabled by default" as the pi itself does not include sshd or even an operating system.  What is enabled will depend on which operating system/configuration the user flashes onto an SD card, or in a few cases which one a re-seller bundles with the board.

Comment: I didn't mean that. All the Pi-specific OSes come `sshd` enabled by default.