# Raspberry Pi disable ssh without screen

Tags: raspbian, ssh

I am unable to connect with my Pi on ssh, with the following error returned:

> **FAIL: Read from socket failed**

I do not have a screen to connect to the Pi. Can I fix this problem by editing data on the SD card on my PC?
The OS is Raspbian, and the model is a Raspberry Pi B.

Here is the debug log:

```
[SSH] OpenSSH_5.6, OpenSSL 1.0.0a 1 Jun 2010 cancel)...

[SSH] debug:
[SSH] Connecting to 192.168.0.105 [192.168.0.105] port 22.

[SSH] debug:
[SSH] successful connection (select got writefds).

[SSH] debug:
[SSH] Connection established.

[SSH] debug:
[SSH] permanently_set_uid: 0/0

[SSH] debug:
[SSH] Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u1

[SSH] debug:
[SSH] match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u1 pat OpenSSH*

[SSH] debug:
[SSH] Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0

[SSH] debug:
[SSH] Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.6

[SSH] Server Version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u1
[SSH] debug:
[SSH] packet_start[20]

[SSH] debug:
[SSH] send: len 904 (includes padlen 4)

[SSH] debug:
[SSH] packet_send done

[SSH] debug:
[SSH] SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent

[SSH] debug:
[SSH] packet_read()

[SSH] FAIL: Connection closed by 192.168.0.105
[SSH] debug:
[SSH] dev_main Unnormal end of SSHThread (longjmp was triggered)

[SSH] debug:
[SSH] platform_shutdown(576, 2)

[SSH] debug:
[SSH] platform_close 576

[SSH] INFO: DISCONNECT
```

After updating the OpenSSH server, here is the new event log:

```
OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.105 [192.168.0.105] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-   4+deb7u1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enabling SSH on RPi without screen - keystrokes for raspi-config?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4444/enabling-ssh-on-rpi-without-screen-keystrokes-for-raspi-config)

Comment: no, i had working ssh before. but now it is broken...i dont know how fix this problem

Comment: Could you please provide logs by cennecting to your RPi with `ssh <RPi's IP address> -v`? (make sure to hide sensitive data)

Comment: its done. im updated the post

Comment: Well, the new logs aren't so helpful. Could you please reconnect with `ssh <RPi's IP address> -vvv` and paste the log?

Comment: i think log with `-vvv` command also aren't so helpful. it is almost the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17427/discussion-between-morgan-courbet-and-undrooleek).

Answer (score 2):

One possible cause of "ssh negotiation succeeds but login immediately dies" is that the file system is 100% full.

Can you mount the SD card on another machine and check for a filled up Linux partition?   The most common cause is huge log files in /var/log; delete some.

Comment: First thing that came to my mind also!  A classic.  UPDATE: But then I read that he updated the SSH server, so probably his fs is not full.

Answer (score 1):

The first line says that you are using the OpenSSH client v5.6.

> [SSH] OpenSSH_**5.6**, OpenSSL 1.0.0a 1 Jun 2010 cancel)...

But your RPi seems to run the OpenSSH daemon v6.0.

> [SSH] Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_**6.0** p1 Debian-4+deb7u1

I don't know the compatibility version chart between OpenSSH servers and clients, but I think that updating your OpenSSH client (from your desktop, laptop, or whatever) should resolve your problem.

Comment: ive just got another event log and edited a post