# Raspberry Pi unreachable over network

Tags: raspbian, networking, raspbian-wheezy

I am trying to get an original model Raspberry Pi working. I've installed 2015-05-05-raspbian-wheezy, and if I boot with a TV connected via composite, I get image on the screen and it gets as far as the `raspi-config` screen. So far, so good, but my wish is to perform a "headless" install - without screen & keyboard. So, I've connected the Pi to my local network via wired connection to my router. I have another computer, and I'm trying to ssh into the Pi from it.

```
sudo arp-scan --interface=wlan0 --localnet
Interface: wlan0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.8.1 with 256 hosts (http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools/arp-scan/)
192.168.100.1   00:0c:c3:7f:7e:63   BeWAN systems

1 packets received by filter, 0 packets dropped by kernel
Ending arp-scan 1.8.1: 256 hosts scanned in 1.948 seconds (131.42 hosts/sec). 1 responded
```

That's my router. In the router's config panel, I can see the Pi and that it has an IP - in this case, 192.168.100.39.

**ssh:**

```
ssh pi@192.168.100.39
ssh: connect to host 192.168.100.39 port 22: No route to host
```

**ping:**

```
ping 192.168.100.39
PING 192.168.100.39 (192.168.100.39) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.100.39 ping statistics ---
75 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 74210ms
```

I got it through a couple of times, but the statistics look like `141 packets transmitted, 1 received, 99% packet loss, time 140674ms`

**nmap:**

```
nmap -Pn 192.168.100.39 -p 22

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-06-16 15:03 EEST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.100.39
Host is up.
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.82 seconds
```

Around the same time as I got a few ping requests through, the output from `ssh` changed to `ssh: connect to host 192.168.100.39 port 22: Connection timed out` sometimes, `no route to host` as before on other times.

**Edit**: I now get consistent, sensible ping responses, with 0% packet loss. I did not change anything, so this is weird, but a change for the better.
Also, the Pi is now visible with **arp-scan**:

```
arp-scan --localnet
Interface: wlan0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.8.1 with 256 hosts (http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools/arp-scan/)
192.168.100.1   00:0c:c3:7f:7e:63   BeWAN systems
192.168.100.39  b8:27:eb:f9:54:da   (Unknown)
```

Comment: Have you enable SSH in RPi ?Please Let me know, i tried same thing yesterday it is working fine for me

Comment: What does it say when you try to ssh to rpi ip ?

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot that (doh!). Updated.

Comment: No I haven't, it's a fresh, untouched flash of the image. It is my understanding that sshd should be enabled by default (?).

Comment: I guess you have to enable it

Comment: It's enabled by default in raspbian wheezy.

Comment: I found [this answer](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4444/enabling-ssh-on-rpi-without-screen-keystrokes-for-raspi-config/8083#8083) about enabling ssh, and followed the instructions, but am stuck at the same point.

Comment: That's strange. Are you sure your rpi is having the same ip, because it doesn't look like it.

Comment: Can you remove HDMI and reboot and see what happens ?

Comment: @dastaan the IP is directly from the router. I'm not sure what you mean wrt. HDMI - I checked `config.txt` and there are no uncommented HDMI entries. The picture does output via composite video, and to my knowledge, the two can't be enabled at the same time (?).

Comment: https://learn.adafruit.com/system/assets/assets/000/003/151/medium800/learn_raspberry_pi_raspi_config_ssh1.png?1396792349

Comment: Didn't you get this window at startup ?

Comment: I get the `raspi-config` window, yes, but mine's different. Only the first nine entries are shown, and SSH is not one of them (as I said, I'm running headless, so I can't navigate the list). I found this piece of documentation: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/
that clearly says "You can enable or disable the SSH server on your Raspberry Pi (**it is enabled by default**)"

Comment: I meant remove display. Just let it run headless, ie Rpi + supply + Ethernet plugged in

Comment: which ssh client software you are using?

Comment: Are you using a home router? The third number in the IP address makes me think that you're not, and that device to device communication may be disabled.

Comment: @AKASH I'm using the OpenSSH client, version 1:6.7p1-6 on Debian.

Comment: @dastaan That's how I'm running it, yes.

Comment: @Jacobm001 Yes I am, a Bewan iBox. I'd like to update that I've gotten ping through, but it's very sporadic (see the edit in the OP).

Comment: Try connecting it via other router - I assume there must be sth wrong as I have exactly the same wheezy version and headless works with no problem.

Comment: I've had vaguely similar problems with poor ping response etc,  it was solved by spotting that CPU usage was maxed, so I killing the culprit and stopped it running on startup

Comment: You don't have to use an old version of raspbian on the original B. I've used jessie with no issues and would expect stretch to work the same way.

Answer (score 1):

On your computer download a program named PuTTy and put the IP address of you Raspberry Pi into it and select the connection type as SSH. This will open a window, you will be prompted to enter your login and password for your Raspberry Pi.

If you want to run fully headless, I recommend using a program called VNC viewer, which allows you to view the Raspberry Pi desktop from your computer wirelessly.

Comment: I'm using the OpenSSH client, version 1:6.7p1-6 on Debian. I have inserted the output of an attempted ssh connection to the OP. I'm aware of VNC, but for now, I have no control of the machine over ssh, which is the problem to begin with.

Comment: I don't knew if you can actually connect because you didn't say yes or no. Can any other device with ssh on your network connect the the pi?

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me once when using the raspi-config utility to enable SSH that something seemed to behave weird, since then i just enable it using the shell.

When making a new install of Raspbian I immediately enable SSH as:

```
sudo systemctl enable ssh
sudo systemctl start ssh
```

Then I can go and SSH to PI from my PC, then update, upgrade and reboot.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade
sudo reboot
```

Then install Samba on it:

```
sudo apt-get -y install samba
```

What Samba gives me is the ability to see the PI`s hostname when I scan the network.