# Cannot connect to raspbian jessie lite but to raspbian jessie

Tags: raspbian, ssh, jessie-lite

I've installed Raspbian Jessie with `dd` to my Pi1-B. Everything works fine and I can connect to it via `ssh`. I do not need any graphical system and want to keep the machine as simple as possible. Therefor I've downloaded and installed Raspbian Jessie Lite. But I cannot get a connection. Error message: `Permission denied, please try again.` The server is running because it says: `debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000`

Is there any difference between the two images that keeps me from accessing the machine with user `pi` and password `raspberry`?

Comment: Hello and welcome. What does the log read after the line you copied? Something about `load_hostkeys:`? It is possible that login is allowed, but restricted to public-key only and not using passwords. Check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` like @fcm's answer suggests.

Comment: It seems that this is not a ssh issue. With the correct adapters I can no test the pi with a screen attached and I can not log in with the known credentials.

Comment: This is strange. All documentation leads to the belief that pi/raspberry is the user/pass for jessie lite too.

Comment: Mea culpa @all! it seems that I mixed up some files or something went wrong with my copy command. I've downloaded it again, pushed it to the card and it works now. Thanks for your hints

Answer (score 66):

From https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/

> As of the November 2016 release, Raspbian has the SSH server disabled
>   by default. You will have to enable it manually. This is done using
>   raspi-config:
>
> Enter `sudo raspi-config` in the terminal, first select `Interfacing options`, then navigate to `ssh`, press `Enter` and select `Enable or disable ssh server`.
>
> For headless setup, SSH can be enabled by placing a file named 'ssh',
>   without any extension, onto the boot partition of the SD card.

Comment: Arg, this was my problem. I can't believe there's no mention of this on the image download page. I've flashed cards for my Pi enough times to not need to read the instructions, what a strange thing to "silently" change.

Comment: I believe it's been changed since people connected Pis to the outside world without changing the default password. Maybe a better idea would have been a prompt to change it on first login?

Comment: wow this took me a long time to figure out. fyi if you are using the headless version "SSH can be enabled by placing a file named 'ssh', without any extension, onto the boot partition of the SD card." so i just ran `cd /Volumes/boot && touch ssh`

Comment: Thanks for this great tip. It was very disorienting to see Raspbian Jessie Lite work with the May 2016 version and go silent with March 2017 version.

Comment: `sudo systemctl enable ssh` should also do the trick

Comment: Minor note: as of at least Jessie Lite 2017-04-10 the magic file can be "ssh.txt" as well as just "ssh", per the code in /lib/systemd/system/sshswitch.service.

Comment: Life saver!! `For headless setup, SSH can be enabled by placing a file named 'ssh', without any extension, onto the boot partition of the SD card`

Answer (score 3):

You may need to enable **SSH**, however, you are receiving a prompt, so most likely is already active, just in case:

```
sudo update-rc.d ssh enable
```

if security is high, edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
sudo /etc/ssh/sshd_config
# comment
#PermitRootLogin without-password
# and add
PermitRootLogin yes
# and also
#StrictModes yes
StrictModes no
```

then, restart the **ssh** service:

```
sudo invoke-rc.d ssh restart
# or
sudo service ssh restart
```

Comment: The user is using Jessie. This uses `systemd` to start services. `systemctl status ssh.service` will show if it is running.

Comment: @Milliways, you are right, my bad, I paste from my old notes. However... `service` is still alive and well. As always, I tried my answer (on Jessie) before posting.

Comment: But the OP has trouble connecting user `pi` not root. So `PermitRootLogin` should not be of relevance?

Comment: @Ghanima, no, no relevance, then applies just the first part: enable **ssh**. However, to allow root  ssh (without ssh-keygen) is a quite common question.

Comment: But we're pretty sure `sshd` is running. Giving `permission denied` errors. Thus I believe it's something in the `sshd_config`.

Comment: Thank you! Started ssh service in blind mode from USB keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable SSH by placing a file called "ssh" at the root of the boot partition. You would do this right after you flash the image to the SD card and before you place the SD card in the Pi.

> 3. ENABLE SSH ON A HEADLESS RASPBERRY PI
>
> For headless setup, SSH can be enabled by placing a file named ssh,
>   without any extension, onto the boot partition of the SD card. When
>   the Pi boots, it looks for the  ssh file. If it is found, SSH is
>   enabled, and the file is deleted. The content of the file does not
>   matter: it could contain text, or nothing at all.

Source: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/

Answer (score 1):

There are no fundamental differences between the configurations. The default password and username are the same.

The error `compat 0x04000000` usually indicates that you're having trouble with ssh keys.  I would check that you client isn't trying to present a key, and that the permissions on the `~/.ssh/` directory are correctly configured.

Answer (score 0):

On 2016-03-18-raspian-jessie-lite

```
sudo update-rc.d ssh enable
```

did it for me instantly, without any ssh restart command

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Nothing in this post helped me, until I found this lines in my /val/log/auth.log file:

```
Jun 15 05:43:31 raspberrypi sshd[1551]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key

Jun 15 05:43:31 raspberrypi sshd[1551]: error: key_load_public: invalid format
```

So found this post on the internet : [how-to-fix-regenerate_ssh_host_keys-failed-on-raspbian-for-raspberryp](https://marcomc.com/2012/09/how-to-fix-regenerate_ssh_host_keys-failed-on-raspbian-for-raspberrypi/)

In short, do the following:

```
sudo ssh-keygen -t 'rsa' -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
sudo ssh-keygen -t 'dsa' -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
sudo ssh-keygen -t 'ecdsa' -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
sudo systemctl restart ssh
```

This fixed the problem of ssh connection to the rpi for me

Answer (score -1):

For anyone struggling with the SSH option disabled as default, I've found a page that has a [list of releases](https://distrowatch.com/?newsid=09208) that can get you on your way to starting headless.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help). Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it is preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. In fact we're [enforcing this policy](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538): please edit so that the answer stands on its own should the link break in the future. If it is not edited within 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki.