# Version for `uname -r` remains despite successful rpi-update

Tags: raspbian, update, rpi-update

I did install my Raspberry PI using [debian-pi/raspbian-ua-netinst](https://github.com/debian-pi/raspbian-ua-netinst) like described [in this SO Post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/36127/12404)

Now `uname -r` returned

```
3.18.0-trunk-rpi
```

When I ran `rpi-update` it seemed to have successfully installed the two upgrade packages (I don't know why there are two):

```
*** Backing up modules 3.18.0-trunk-rpi
#############################################################
 This update bumps to rpi-4.1.y linux tree
 Be aware there could be compatibility issues with some drivers
 Discussion here:
 https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=113753
##############################################################
```

So `ls /lib/modules/` now returns three modules:

```
3.18.0-trunk-rpi
4.1.6+  
4.1.6-v7+
```

When I now run `rpi-update` it tells me that the system is up to date:

```
 *** Raspberry Pi firmware updater by Hexxeh, enhanced by AndrewS and Dom  
 *** Performing self-update  
 *** Relaunching after update  
 *** Raspberry Pi firmware updater by Hexxeh, enhanced by AndrewS and Dom  
 *** Your firmware is already up to date
```

However, after a reboot, `uname -r` still shows `3.18.0-trunk-rpi` rather than one of the newly installed upgrades.

I wonder how I can now update my PI to the latest firmware.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mention a specific kernel version in /boot/cmdline.txt?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at /boot you should have 4055296 Aug 30 15:47 kernel.img (the date will of course differ, depending when you updated). The earlier kernel was 3974884.

`rpi-update` was notorious for installation problems. I don't know how it is now, but I haven't used it for years. You should use `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` to install the latest.

Comment: I did run those commands as well, but `uname -r` still shows the old version

Answer (score 2):

The kernel to load is specified in `/boot/config.txt`. The `rpi-update` script should have created a `kernel.img` file in `/boot/` but the `config.txt` file is still pointing at the old kernel. By default, the Raspberry Pi will boot the file named `kernel.img` if you don't specify an alternative. More information about `config.txt` can be found on the [official site](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md).

To fix this, simply look in `/boot/config.txt` for a line starting with `kernel=` and comment it out by putting a `#` at the start, then reboot the Pi to load the new kernel named `kernel.img`.

You can do this from the command line with the commands:

```
sudo sed -i 's/^kernel=/#kernel=/' /boot/config.txt
sudo reboot
```