# Enable ssh and connect to a wifi network without a keyboard or a screen

Tags: wifi, ssh, raspbian-jessie

[This similar question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38/prepare-for-ssh-without-a-screen) has a lot of answers, none of which works anymore. Given that is already a little old, I'm asking the same quesion, for the current distribution of raspian (jessie 2017-04-10).

Comment: How about you actually post your question in full here. If that question gets deleted in the future the link will become useless. How do you know none of the solutions don't work anymore?

Comment: The question is actually the title (not really frased as a question, but still). I"m new here. Is it customary to repeat the question in the description? Yes, I tried almost all of those solutions (I may have skipped a couple which had no upvotes), and none worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, plug the sd card into a computer. Then, there are basically three things that you probably want to do:

1. In order to connect to a wifi network, edit /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf and add the following lines:

   ```
   network={
       ssid="my-network-name"
       psk="my-network-pass"
       key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
   }
   ```
2. In order to enable ssh (disabled by default in jessie 2017-04-10), create an empty file simply named `ssh` in /boot/.
3. Finally, plug the card into your raspberry and, from a computer that is also connected to the same wifi network, do:

   `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local`

(instead of raspberrypi.local, you can write the ip address of the pi, but you need to know it somehow -e.g., by looking at your router clients list-).

Answer (score 5):

On startup, [Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/another-update-raspbian/) checks the contents of the boot directory for specific files:

- If it detects a file called `wpa_supplicant.conf`, Raspbian will copy
  the file into `/etc/wpa_supplicant`, replacing any existing
  `wpa_supplicant.conf` file that may be there. The file in the boot
  directory is then removed.
- If an empty file named `ssh` is detected, Raspbian will adjust its
  settings to accept SSH connections. The ssh file is then deleted.