# Raspberry Pi Zero W headless using wpa_supplicant.conf not working

Tags: wifi, pi-zero-w

I am trying to start up my Raspberry Pi Zero W completely headless, but somehow it won't connect to my WiFi. Here's what I did:

1. Plug SD card running **RASPBIAN JESSIE WITH PIXEL** (should it be something else?) into my Windows PC
2. Create an `ssh` file on the root of the SD card
3. Create a `wpa_supplicant.conf` file with the following content:

**wpa_supplicant.conf**:

```
network={
    ssid="My WiFi 2.4"
    psk="mypassword123"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

Then I plug the SD card into the Pi, boot it up, but it never appears as a client on my router, nor can I see an indication saying it's connected when I hook it up using my HDMI cable.

My WiFi settings:

[image]

When I plug the SD card back into the PC again, the files are missing (I assume it does its magic and applies the settings, then removes the files afterwards). However, when I look at the monitor, it shows SSH has been enabled, so I know *that* works.

What can I do here? I'm clueless right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Went with PiBakery (which is awesome). Just installed Jessie Lite and I am now hooked up to the WiFi. Completely headless.

Comment: I don't know why your original didn't work, but the process is documented in https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/67016/8697 . This also explains where the file is located; NOTE you need `sudo` to view it.

Comment: @Milliways Yeah, it's weird why it didn't work. Oh well, at least I found a solution.

Comment: PiBakery is very interesting.  Hadn't heard of it before.  Good job.

Comment: Here's a link to PiBakery: http://pibakery.org/index.html

Answer (score 22):

The accepted answer does not give a solution to anyone having this problem.

From a point on (maybe debian jessie?), **the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` requires these lines on top of the network configs**:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
country=US
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="Home Wifi"
    psk="mypassword"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

Change the country code and WiFi info to yours.

[Official documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/headless.md)

Comment: Thanks. You're right, the first three lines are needed to apply the network configuration without banish the configuration every time.

Answer (score 4):

You probably created the file "wpa_supplicant.conf" using a Windows format for end-of-line characters which the Raspberry Pi can't understand. Check to see if "wpa_supplicant.conf" has a Unix format for EOL characters. You can check this and convert ifd needed to Unix format, using a advanced editor like Notepad++ (which is free software for Windows downloadable at https://notepad-plus-plus.org).

Answer (score 2):

I have found that the syntax of wpa_supplicant.conf is very picky. For example the line "priority = 1" fails whereas "prioriy=1" works. Any syntax errors will cause failure.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Raspberry Pi Zero W:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=UK
network={
 ssid="my-ssid"
 psk="my-network-password"
 key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

**then:** `sudo rfkill unblock all`
the wifi came up and when I rebooted, to make sure, it stayed up.

Comment: How do you run a command without first connecting to the pi? The question noted a fully headless setup.

Comment: Hi, as the top of this thread, I created both `ssh` and `wpa_supplicant.conf` on the system where I  created the boot image, **not** on the Pi Zero W.

Comment: I was referring to when you said you ran `sudo rfkill unblock all`. In my case it was the line endings for the wpa_supplicant file were in CRLF and not LF.

Answer (score 2):

Another problem that unfortunately affects some versions of Raspbian/Rasperry Pi OS is that the `rfkill` status of the Wi-Fi interface is not unblocked so the wifi doesn't connect. This can be checked by logging in on the console and running:

```
rfkill
```

For the Wi-Fi to work it should show that the `wlan0` device is `unblocked` in the the SOFT and HARD colums. If the device isn't connecting due to this issue then it will show as `blocked` in SOFT column.

This can only be remedied by mounting the image and changing the config as per [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127705/automatically-run-rfkill-unblock-on-startup), or by booting it and logging in on the console and typing:

```
sudo rfkill unblock wifi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Mac be sure to turn on ['Show file extensions' in Finder](https://support.apple.com/sv-se/guide/mac-help/mchlp2304/mac) or the file could get a additional .txt extension wpa_supplicant.conf.txt) if created in Texteditor.

Answer (score -3):

Dropping the `wpa_supplicant.conf` along with the `ssh` file into `/boot` should have worked. (I honestly don't know why it wouldn't, in your case)

Anyway, on the bright-side, you do have SSH working which is all you need to configure and control a headless Pi. Try a manually configuring `wpa_supplicant` directly by editing the file in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`. The command in the ssh terminal is as follows:

```
sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Detailed and complete instructions may be found in the reference below in the official docs.

Reference: [RPi Foundation Docs: Setting wifi up via the command line](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md)

Comment: That's great and all, but how would I SSH into my Pi, if it's not connected to the network? And no, I won't do any crazy workaround to enable the Pi as an ethernet adapter, which I can SSH into through USB.

Comment: My bad, forgot that the Zeros doesn't have any other ports other than that microusb.