# Seeking image file preconfigured for headless Pi Zero W

Tags: pi-zero-w, image

Rather than take a distro and follow instructions to configure it, I am looking for a preconfigured image file which I can write to SD and just use.

Is there one, or is configuration absolutely necessary?

---

[Update] As @Jaromanda points out in comments, configuration ***is*** absolutely necessary.

Perhaps a front end script, runnable in Windows / Linux to ask a few questions and configure a standard distro would be nice.

Alternatively the Onion Omega range, (which is a great price for price competitor), [comes with an access point enabled](https://docs.onion.io/omega2-docs/the-omega-and-wireless-connectivity.html), which makes headless configuration ***much*** simpler. A similar distro would be very welcome. In fact, I will write to the maintainer of Rapsbian and suggest it.

I would alsoaccept a distro where I can see the Linux file system on the SD card. For Raspbian, all that I can see are a bunch of `*.pdb` files, which I imagine are decompressed at boot time.  If I could see the file system under Windows, I could easily edit `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` etc.

---

[Further update] it looks like [this](https://davesteele.github.io/comitup/) will do it. I will try it tonight & report back

Comment: configuration is necessary ... not all wifi uses the same SSID and password for a start. Also, you'll be lucky to find a pre-configured image that exactly meets your requirements (timezone, keyboard layout, default language just to name a few)

Comment: Feel free to post that as an answer. I can live with keyboard, etc layout, if only the Wi-Fi were fixed, but I take your point there. Perhaps affront end script, runnable in Windows / Linux to ask a few questions and configure a standard distro would be nice. I tried Pi Bakery, but it didn't want to write to my SD card & the v2 beta just crashed (which I reported)

Comment: actually, I won't yet. Is the reason for this because you want multiple (read dozens or more) installs? Or is this just a one off for making the install onto 0W easier on yourself?

Comment: The latter. I found an old Pi Zero W at the back of a drawer. I haven't used it for a year. I think that I remember set up being straightforward last time. The SD card was missing, so I took a new one and basically wasted most of the weekend being unable to connect via Putty (and I have no display to help)

Answer (score 2):

I have an image at the bottom of this article -

https://robotzero.one/pi-zero-w-bluetooth-voice/

If you follow the instructions under **Headless Install of Raspbian Stretch Lite** you should be able to connect to it.

Comitup looks like a good bet as well.

This answer might help with any problems with the supplicant.conf file :
[Raspberry Pi Zero W headless using wpa_supplicant.conf not working](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/67649/raspberry-pi-zero-w-headless-using-wpa-supplicant-conf-not-working?rq=1)

And of course you can start with a fresh image from here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/